# Custom tabs in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to change the content of the tab header but am struggling. I can see that it is possible to pass a View to the setIndicator() method. I tried this and got a removeParent() warning which I dont understand. Has anyone managed to do this successfully. If so can you explain how you did it please?

Clive

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when you use the same view in different tabs. You must use a different view. This is what I did:

```java
view.setImageResource(R.drawable.videotab);
view1.setImageResource(R.drawable.musictab);

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, CustomList.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Video").setIndicator(view)
.setContent(intent);

tabHost.addTab(spec);


intent = new Intent().setClass(this, CustomListOne.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Music").setIndicator(view1)
.setContent(intent);

tabHost.addTab(spec);
tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use different `View`s. You can simply inflate the same layout again when you need it. That means you inflate your layout, set everything you need on your different `View`s and then you set it as your indicator. If you need another tab just do it again.